# Showing all error messages at the same time in form validation

Tags: javascript, html

Why are my conditional statements not working properly? I want to display  bothe error messages at the same time.

```js
function validate() {
  if (firstName.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "*Field is empty";
    return false;
  } else if (lastName.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML = "*Field is empty";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="action.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span>Name</span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='First Name'" />&nbsp;
    <label id="error"></label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name (optional)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Middle Name (optional)'" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Last Name'" />&nbsp;
    <label id="errorTwo"></label>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `}`. Are you seeing any errors in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: You've pasted the script tag outside the scope of the HTML tag which is your first problem, your second problem is that you haven't declared firstname or last name

Comment: sorry, i just not included it in my post but i have closing in my actual code.. i don't have any errors it just doesn't work the way i want it to be

Comment: so... syntax errors in the JS code, no form input fields, undefined JS variables (where are `firstName` and `lastName` defined?), accessing undefined DOM ids, etc... in short this code is totally useless.

Comment: @JuanCarlosDeLuna Please paste your full script and the target HTML for said script so we can actually help you

Comment: i just posted my edited question sorry its my first time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional statements are working correctly, your understanding of them is a little off though.

An `if` / `else if` statement will stop running when a condition is matched, so if firstName.value is empty, then that `if` statement will be matched and the code will exit there and not evaluate the rest of the conditions.

You want to use independent conditional statements for each test, and instead of returning either true or false, set a variable to true or false and return that after the conditional checks.

So...

```
function validate()
{
  var valid = true;
  if(firstName.value=="")
  {
      document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
      valid = false;
  }

  if(lastName.value=="")
  {
      document.getElementById('errorTwo').innerHTML="*Field is empty";
      valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
}
```

Just a note on the code itself, the above comments are mainly correct, if you post your entire code, you'll probably get more helpful responses. Also, you can eliminate the `==""` part of the checks and just test the value of the variable as an empty string evaluates to false.

Comment: No worries. Hopefully everything I've said makes sense to you. If you've got questions, just ask and I'll try and answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't chain the validations together with if-else otherwise if the first name validation fails, then you will never check the last name validation.

Answer (score 0):

Help yourself by quickly creating a JsFiddle :-)

Here it is: 
http://jsfiddle.net/23tnpve4/1/

You will easily see some issues by trying:

- As others mentioned, missing brackets etc
- As others mentioned, if the first test fails the other fields are not checked so errors can by corrected only step by step.
- There is no code that refreshes your error DIVs. In a new form check, the error fields have to be cleared first. Checking forms are cycles with several possible start statuses.

Try to collect the status of fields in an array and work them later, something like this:

```
window.validate = function()
{
  var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
  var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');

  // Clear
  firstName.val('');
  lastName.val('');

  // Check
  var errorNames = [];
  if(firstName.value=="")
  {
    errorNames.push('firstName');
  }

  if(lastName.value=="")
  {
    errorNames.push('lastName');
  }

  // Inform
  for (var i=0; i<errorNames.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(errorNames[i]).innerHTML="*Field is empty";
  }

  // Return value
  return errorNames.length == 0;
}
```

The concept of this code will work more intuitively. I haven't checked it against typos, it is a draft, but I do hope it will help you.